# On showing that a certain level-set defines a regular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

> Let $f: \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R, f(x) =2x_1e^{x_2}+2x_2e^{x_3}+2x_3e^{x_4}$. Show that the level-set $S=f^{-1}(2)$ defines a regular surface.

From Wikipedia, I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Regular_surfaces_in_Euclidean_space) definition for regular surfaces.

Computing the gradient I have that $\nabla f(x)=(2e^{x_2}, 2x_1e^{x_2} + 2e^{x_3}, 2x_2e^{x_3}+ 2e^{x_4}, 2x_3e^{x_4})$. It's clear that $f$ is smooth. Now since $\nabla f \ne 0$ I get that by the by the implicit function theorem there exists an smooth function $g : U \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $\varphi(x_2,x_3,x_3) = (g(x_2,x_3,x_4), x_2,x_3,x_3)$.

Now according to the Wikipedia link, it seems that I would need to show that the rank of this parametrization $\varphi$ would be $3$. I'm a bit stuck here, how should I approach this?

Comment: The implicit function theorem gives also a form for the deritive of the implicit function in terms of the data you have. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), in the section "statement of the theorem"

Comment: I'm not familiar with the case for $\mathbb{R}^4$. For the $2$-dimensional case one has $\varphi'(x) = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$ right?

Comment: this is similar but as the functions are not scalar function this is not a division but an inversion of linear application. The formula is given in the wikipedia article

Comment: @DIdier_ I see it's the one with the matrix product involving the inverse of the Jacobian, I cannot seem to be able to compute it although...

Comment: You do not have to compute the matrix to compute its rank

Comment: In order to find rank$(D\varphi(x_2,x_3,x_4))$ shouldn't I first find the rank of $Dg(x_2, x_3, x_4)$?

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid a messy computation in the application of the implicit function by using the inverse function theorem instead. Consider $f(x,y,z,w) =2xe^{y}+2ye^{z}+2ze^{w}-2.$

The level set we want to analyze is $S=\{(x,y,z,w):f(x,y,z,w)=0\}.$ Now,

$\partial_xf(x,y,z,w)=2e^y;\ \partial_yf(x,y,z,w)=2xe^y+2e^z$

$\partial_zf(x,y,z,w)=2ye^z+2e^w;\ \partial_wf(x,y,z,w)=2ze^w.$

There are no critical points, since $e^y\neq 0$ so every point $p$ on the level set is regular.

Now take the map $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto (f(x,y,z,w),y,z,w)$ and compute its Jacobian:

$\mathcal J=\begin{pmatrix}
2e^y &2xe^y+2e^z  &2ye^z+2e^w  &2ze^w \\ 
 0&1  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}.$

It's easy to see that this is never zero so NOW we apply the inverse function theorem to get an open neighborhood $p\in U_p$ such that $(U_p,(f,y,z,w))$ is a chart in $\mathbb R^4$ with the property that on $U_p\cap S,$ the first coordinate vanishes. And this, by definition, makes $S$ a regular level set.